# Different syntax errors hide line in output

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback

I have a script which calls `compile`.

```
try:
    code = compile('3 = 3', 'test', 'exec')
except Exception as e:
    sys.stderr.write(''.join(traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)))
```

`3 = 3` results in:

```
File "test", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Whereas `3 = 3a` actually prints the line

```
File "test", line 1
    3 = 3a
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea why that is?

Comment: Usually there is first a lexer phase when parsing data, and then a parsing phase. The second code fragment, will already error on the lexer phase, whereas the first one will error on the parser phase. `3a` is an invalid token. Whereas `3 = 3` is invalid grammar.

Comment: So the output is correct? If I put `3 = 3` in a file, it prints out the correct error including the line

Comment: Darn, misdiagnosed, will have to rewrite my answer. The parser has the source, the compiler doesn't, and the latter determines that `3 = 3` is a syntax error. Without source, no decent `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python produces `SyntaxError` exceptions in two places:

1. when parsing, which is driven by the Python grammar
2. when creating the Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) from the parse result; the AST drives the compiler.

That's because the Python grammar has a few special cases where it was easier to keep the grammar simple but then make additional checks *once parsing is complete* and building the AST where additional syntax checks are done.

Assignments are one of those places, because the rules for what is allowed on the left of the `=` sign differs from what is allowed on the right but are still closely related. The  left-hand side is the *target* side, and targets can be structured like lists or tuples (unpacking assignments), and you can assign to attributes or indexing operations (`listobj[1] = ...`, etc.).  But to have the parser detect that a target is actually a literal and not a variable name or attribute, etc, would require a very different parser structure, so this is left to the AST instead.

So your `3 = 3` error passes the parsing stage but then fails at the later AST 'assignment target' check phase, while `3 = 3a` falls at the parser stage (where `3a` is easy to spot as an error).

To give you a good syntax error, exceptions raised by the parser contain the source code line in the exception:

```
>>> try:
...     code = compile('3 = 3a', 'test', 'exec')
... except Exception as e:
...     print(repr(e))
...
SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('test', 1, 6, '3 = 3a\n'))
```

Note the `('test', 1, 6, '3 = 3a\n')` tuple in the exception; these are available via the `SyntaxError` attributes `filename`, `lineno` (the line number), `offset` (the column offset) and `text` for the source code line itself. For the parser, this is easily provided, as it has access to the source code.

But the *AST* doesn't have the source code. It only has the filename, line number, column, and [parse tree objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html). It does not have the original source text. It would normally try to read that from the filename, but `test` is not actually a file. So the line is empty:

```
>>> try:
...     code = compile('3 = 3', 'test', 'exec')
... except Exception as e:
...     print(repr(e))
...
SyntaxError('cannot assign to literal', ('test', 1, 1, ''))
```

You can test for this and fix it by replacing the `SyntaxError` exception with a new one with the empty string replaced with your source text:

```
>>> source = '3 = 3'
>>> try:
...     code = compile(source, 'test', 'exec')
... except Exception as e:
...     if isinstance(e, SyntaxError) and not e.text:
...         sline = source.splitlines(True)[e.lineno - 1]
...         e = SyntaxError(e.msg, (e.filename, e.lineno, e.offset, sline))
...     sys.stderr.write(''.join(traceback.format_exception_only(type(e), e)))
...
  File "test", line 1
    3 = 3
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
```

Note that for a multi-line source string you’d want to split that source into lines and use the `.lineno` attribute to select the indicated source line.

The alternative is to write the source code to a temporary filename, and pass that filename to `compile()` so that when a `SyntaxError` exception is found when building the AST, Python can then open that temporary file and find the corresponding text line.

Note that when you use the special filename `'<string>'`, that no attempt is made to find the source code for a line and `e.text` is set to `None`:

```
>>> try:
...     code = compile('3 = 3', '<string>', 'exec')
... except Exception as e:
...     print(repr(e))
...
SyntaxError('cannot assign to literal', ('<string>', 1, 1, None))
```

and when the `.text` attribute is set to `None`, the `traceback` module forgoes printing the line-and-marker section.

If you are interested in exactly why the Python grammar parser won't detect literals in the assignment target, you might be interested in the work Guido van Rossum is doing in [writing a different parser for Python](https://medium.com/@gvanrossum_83706/peg-parsing-series-de5d41b2ed60), which includes exposition on why the current parser works the way it does and how an alternative parser model can avoid these issues.

Comment: Holy moly! That is an explanation! How can I mark this as an answer twice? Thank you so much!